# Background Threads are getting shown up

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio-2013, threadpool

Consider the following code.

**In Main**

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Hi,i);
}

static void Hi(object arg)
{
    int n = (int)arg;
    Console.WriteLine("Thread ID:{0}  IsBackground:{1} HI Joshua.. You got:{2} ", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
        Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground,n);

}
```

I am getting the following output

```
Thread ID:10  IsBackground:True HI Joshua.. You got:2
Thread ID:10  IsBackground:True HI Joshua.. You got:3
Thread ID:10  IsBackground:True HI Joshua.. You got:4
Thread ID:10  IsBackground:True HI Joshua.. You got:6
Thread ID:10  IsBackground:True HI Joshua.. You got:7
Thread ID:10  IsBackground:True HI Joshua.. You got:8
Thread ID:10  IsBackground:True HI Joshua.. You got:9
Thread ID:11  IsBackground:True HI Joshua.. You got:5
Thread ID:13  IsBackground:True HI Joshua.. You got:1
Thread ID:12  IsBackground:True HI Joshua.. You got:0
```

My Question is that since threadpools threads have background property true so why they are getting shown up in my output?
It would also be nice if somebody could direct me a referece or book where I could get examples of threadpool working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be confused about what a [*background thread*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) is.

> Background threads are identical to foreground threads, except that background threads do not prevent a process from terminating.

The term "background thread" does  suggest something that runs in the background, unseeable by the user but that but that is contrary to the documentation.

You can read more about background threads [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339syd0(v=vs.110).aspx) and more about threading in general [here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/) or [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/).

Answer (score 1):

> When a console application starts, the operating system automatically
>   associates three I/O streams with the console: standard input stream,
>   standard output stream, and standard error output stream. Your
>   application can read user input from the standard input stream; write
>   normal data to the standard output stream; and write error data to the
>   standard error output stream. These streams are presented to your
>   application as the values of the Console.In, Console.Out, and
>   Console.Error properties. By default, the value of the In property is
>   a System.IO.TextReader object, and the values of the Out and Error
>   properties are System.IO.TextWriter objects. However, you can set
>   these properties to streams that do not represent the console; for
>   example, you can set these properties to streams that represent files.
>   To redirect the standard input, standard output, or standard error
>   stream, call the Console.SetIn, Console.SetOut, or Console.SetError
>   method, respectively. I/O operations that use these streams are
>   synchronized, which means that multiple threads can read from, or
>   write to, the streams.

[Console Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

ThreadPool's threads are background threads but they can access static `Console` class and call it's static method `WriteLine` and write in the output.

you can learn more about threads in C# [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)